# How to use two database columns in associative array as key and value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to create an associative array in order to turn 2 columns (name, value) into something with the same effect as `$name => value`

What is the best way to code that?

```
while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
    $id = $row->id;
    $nom_variable = $row->nom_variable;
    $valeur_variable = $row->valeur_variable;
}
```

Comment: Post your code please, the part where you get the data and fail achieving your goal so we can help you

Comment: @MehdiBounya updated

Comment: Why don't you store the data as an array with like this: `$array['name'] = 'value'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = array();

while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
    $result[$row->nom_variable] = $row->valeur_variable;
}
```

This will create an associative array of all your rows, with the values from the "name" column as the keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot working fine, I'll dig that way. You have so much simplified my mind. much appreciated